Plot with date on x, time of day on y, and value
Trying to do a three-variable plot in matplotlib with a pandas data frame arranged as follows (third column value would be a color, green to red/low to high):
Date       Time     Value
2023-11-01 11:22:34 59.0
2023-11-01 11:25:26 65.0
.
.
.

I cannot get this thing to plot without an error about a time value has to be a float, etc.
x = pandas.read_xml('/Users/steven/Downloads/apple_health_export/export.xml', xpath='//Record', attrs_only=True,parse_dates=["creationDate","startDate","endDate"])
x.value=pandas.to_numeric(x.value,errors='coerce')
x = x[x.value.notnull()]
data = x[x.type == 'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate']
data['Date']=[datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in data['endDate']]
data['Time']=[datetime.datetime.time(d) for d in data['endDate']]


It sounds like Matplotlib wants time to be a float and it looks like it is some kind of datetime. Take a look at Pandas datetime accessors to help sort this out. To get hour of day, as a numeric type, you would use something like data["Time"].dt.hour

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors

can you make this a [MCVE], and provide the full error message (and which line of your code is producing the error)?

What is unsatisfactory for you, the OP, in my answer below?


As it seems Matplotlib doesn't like time objects on the y axis, so what you need to do is

convert the array of time objects to hours (see code below)
format a little bit the y axis, adding minor ticks, major ticks properly labeled and a double horizontal grid.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, time, timedelta
from random import randint

################ Generation of fake data ###############################
one_day = timedelta(days=1)
days = [date(2024,9,1)]
for i in range(12): days.append(days[-1]+one_day)
vmin, vmax = 30, 70
samplemin, samplemax = 10, 20
secmin, secmax = 0, 24*3600-1
data = []
for day in days:
    for sample in range(randint(samplemin, samplemax)):
        secs = randint(secmin, secmax)
        mins, secs = divmod(secs, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        val = randint(vmin, vmax)
        data = data + [[day, time(hours, mins, secs), val]]
days, times, vals = zip(*data)
################ End of faking data ####################################

################ Converting time object to hours #######################
times_hours = [(t.hour*3600+t.minute*60+t.second)/3600 for t in times]
    
################ Plotting ##############################################
plt.figure(figsize=(11,4), layout='constrained')
plt.scatter(days, times_hours, c=vals,
    vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap='RdYlGn_r')
plt.colorbar()

################ Settings for the y axis ###############################
plt.yticks(range(0, 25),  minor=1)
plt.yticks(range(0, 25, 3), 
    '00:00 03:00 06:00 09:00 12:00 15:00 18:00 21:00 00:00'.split())
plt.grid(axis='y', which='minor', ls='--', lw=0.5)
plt.grid(axis='y')

################ DONE ##################################################
plt.show()


I did figure out that it required using matplot's date2num or datestr2num to convert the date/times into numeric values that can be understood by the plotter.
